# Java - wrapper classes and hashCode()

Tags: java, hashcode, wrapper

is there any difference b/w value returned by Integer's `hashCode()` and `intValue()`? Can hashcode be negative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no difference, and thus yes, it can be negative or zero.

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29):

> **Returns:**  a hash code value for this object, equal to the primitive int value represented by this `Integer` object.

Comment: Integer i = new Integer(-1); Map map = new HashMap(); map.put(i, "test"); // does this throw indexoutofboundsexception??

Comment: @Arjun: Of course not, Maps don't have indexes.  They have keys, and the type and value of the keys are irrelevant as long as they properly implement equals and hashCode (for a HashMap anyway).

Comment: AFAIK, hashmap internally maintains an array of linked lists. map.put(i, "test"); // internally, it would be array[i.hashCode()] = "test", so i ran into this doubt. please, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Arjun: it does, but it handles all hashCode values just fine.    If it didn't, you couldn't do this: `map.put("Hello, world!", someObj);`.  Negative hashCode values are just as common as positive hashCode values in a uniformly-distributed hash.  But you don't really think each hash map has an array of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to accomodate all *positive* hashCodes, do you?  There is simple modular arithmetic to transform any int into a valid bucket index.

Comment: yeah, thxs a lot Mark, looking like bucket_index = (i.hashCode() && 0x7FFFFFFFF) % hashmap_size does the trick here.

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.hashCode()` just returns the value, yes... although it's not a good idea to rely on that. The return value of a hash code should really just be used as an opaque value without attaching any particular meaning to it - *only* equality should really be taken into account. Even if `Integer.hashCode()` is *documented* to just return the value (EDIT: it is; see other answer), I'd be very wary of any code which would break if the implementation changed to return (say) `value + 1`.

The return value of `hashCode()` is certainly allowed to be negative - both here and in general.